# template field width is not increasing in grid view in asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview, templatefield

i have used one template field for add edit, update, delete and cancel image  icons. but edit and delete template field width is small and these two images are displaying on by one vertically due to less width . how to increase width of template field so that it can display two images in one line horizontally

```
  <asp:TemplateField>

     <ItemStyle Width="80px" />
<HeaderStyle  Width="80px" />
 <FooterStyle Width="80px" /> 
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="img/edit.png" ToolTip="Edit" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="img/delete.PNG" ToolTip="Delete" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="img/icon-update.png" ToolTip="Update" Height="18px" Width="18px" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="img/icon-Cancel.png" ToolTip="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" Height="16px" Width="16px" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wrap your buttons in a div, with a CSS style to set the width.

Define a selector in your stylesheet as follows:

```
.buttonColumnWidth
{
    width: 80px; /* change this value as required */
}
```

Then, make these changes to your Gridview:

```
    <asp:TemplateField>

         <ItemStyle Width="80px" />
         <HeaderStyle  Width="80px" />
         <FooterStyle Width="80px" /> 
            <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="buttonColumnWidth">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="img/edit.png" ToolTip="Edit" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="img/delete.PNG" ToolTip="Delete" />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <div class="buttonColumnWidth">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="img/icon-update.png" ToolTip="Update" Height="18px" Width="18px" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="img/icon-Cancel.png" ToolTip="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" Height="16px" Width="16px" />
            </div>
        </EditItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```